# NodeJS --> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner to NodeJS. I was trying to import a module `fs.readFileSync`
I used import { readFileSync } from 'fs' as per the NodeJS docs,
But I keep getting the below error,

**ERROR**----->> `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

**My Research**

->I found that adding `type:module` in `package.json` file solves this issue.

**My Doubt**

->I want to know why this cannot be imported as per documentation??

Code

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
fs.writeFileSync('notes.txt','This was read by NodeJS')
```

**Full error**

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: _"Node.js treats JavaScript code as CommonJS modules by default. Authors can tell Node.js to treat JavaScript code as ECMAScript modules via the .mjs file extension, the package.json "type" field, or the --input-type flag. See [Modules: Packages](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system) for more details."_ ([Source](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#introduction))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, for a `.js` file, nodejs first looks in the package.json file for the module type.  If no module type is found there, then it goes by the file extension of the file.  It it's a `.js` file, then it assumes it's a CommonJS module (where you use `require()`, not `import`).  If it's a `.mjs` file, then it assumes it's a ESM file (where you use `import`).

As you've discovered, you can override the handling of file extensions by specifying the `type` as `module` in the `package.json` file so that `.js` files can use `import`.

You can tell in your stack trace that the file loading is being done by: `internal/modules/cjs/loader` where the `cjs` means `CommonJS` so it's definitely trying to load the file as a CommonJS module.

---

If you wonder why things are set up this way, it's because of nodejs history.  Originally, all there were was CommonJS files - that was the only module type for many years.  So, for backwards compatibility, if no module type is specified in either the `package.json` file or via a special file extension, then nodejs assumes a CommonJS file so that it remains compatible with older modules that don't know anything about the newer module types.

As for why you can't use `import` in CommonJS files, this was clearly a decision that the nodejs architects probably considered carefully.  The challenge is that some parts of the ESM module specification are incompatible with some things in the CommonJS module format.  So, rather than try to cram the features of both modules into one format, they decided to have two completely separate formats.  This avoids conflicts between the two architectures, but creates this need to figure out which module type is being used.

---

Here's the nodejs documentation on how nodejs chooses a module type:

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system

Comment: Hi,thankyou for the answer.You made it clear.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#determining-module-system

Comment: @jfriend00 thankyou..Marked it..

Comment: @devanil - Great, glad to help.